# Instantiating a .NET class derived from Java.Lang.Object throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

If I try to instantiate a .NET class derived from `Java.Lang.Object`, a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. This is easy to reproduce in a most basic project: create a new Android app using the Single-View App template, and add something like this:

```cs
public class Test1
{
}

public class Test2 : Java.Lang.Object
{
}
```

Then in the activity constructor:

```cs
var t1 = new Test1();
var t2 = new Test2();
```

The first line succeeds, the second line throws the exception. This happens both in the emulator and on the real device.

What am I missing? I'm using VS2017 and API 25 in case it's relevant. It seems like what I'm doing here must be a basic mistake, yet I couldn't find anything in Google on this particular issue.

Comment: You aren't missing anything, This is a known issue: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues

Comment: If you can attach your reproduction to this question, it would help us track this issue down further. We have a reproduction, but it's a bit complex.

Comment: @JonDouglas attached to [bug 61073](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61073).

Comment: Check if this isn't the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991044/xamarin-classnotfoundexception